# How to use Walmart API with iOS app in Xcode? (swift language)

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, walmart-api

I've recently installed Walmart's API into my iOS app. The app's purpose is for the user to search for items using Walmart's API and then display the queried items to the user. However I am having a hard time finding any examples on how to use Walmart's API with Xcode and Swift language. Was curious if anyone could point me in the direction of how to properly use the API while using Swift language or if anyone has experience using the Walmart API in Xcode? I feel like it shouldn't be hard to accomplish what I am trying to do but right now I am a bit lost. All help and advice is appreciated in advance! Thanks.

Comment: Please post some relevant part of the code you have done already and state your expectations about it. You will get very little from StackOverflow if you do not post your code too.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever An API is Created The Author gives out a Documentation, about the usage of the API, Requests Parameters etc.

So, Go through the Documentation of Your Needed API,
Once the Requests Are made in-app, they Generally respond you in JSON, XML etc.

Using these Incoming data you can Populate data in your APP